# AJAX call received by servlet but no response is given

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, servlets, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple chrome application that sends a request to a servlet running on tomcat 7.0. The request is successfully received by the servlet, but the chrome application never gets a response. The chrome application receives status 0 and readyState 4, and makes a call with:

```
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { alert(xmlhttp.status + " " + xmlhttp.readyState); }
 xmlhttp.open("GET", http://localhost:8084/NewServlet");
 xmlhttp.send(null);
```

My manifest for the chrome application contains:

```
"permissions": [
    "http://localhost/",
    "tabs"
 ]
```

The servlet itself opens the stream to the browser and prints a message. Anyone have an idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `The servlet itself opens the stream to the browser and prints a message`, since servlets cannot do that. But if your function is being called and `readyState` is 4 then it looks like the response was returned, except the status code is garbage. Are you missing with the HTTP status code within the servlet itself?

Comment: The servlet has an HTTPResponse object, which is the object I am speaking of when handling responses from the browser. Do you have to manually set the status code for a servlet, I thought that if the request was handled then it would be defaulted to 200.

Answer (score 0):

Change `"http://localhost/"` to `"http://localhost/*"`. The first will only allow requests that do not have a path of `/NewServlet`.